# Raku last on non-loops

Tags: block, exit, raku

I have something that I can do easily in Perl, but not in Raku without fiddling around with flag variables.  Here's the Perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

MAIN_BLOCK: {
        foreach $item (1 2 3 4 5) {
                $item == 6 and last MAIN_BLOCK;
        }
        print "No items matched!\n";
}
```

The relevant difference here is that Perl will allow you to use last to exit from any labelled block.  Raku will only do this if the block is a loop.

Is there a good way to do this?  I feel like there should be a phaser for this, but haven't figured out how to do it without flag variables, which seem like they should be avoidable.

Thanks,

Comment: In theory the appropriate Raku incantation would be `leave MAIN_BLOCK` (instead of `last MAIN_BLOCK`). In practice it will currently net you a `leave not yet implemented. Sorry.` message. Filed many years ago as [`leave` NYI](https://github.com/Raku/old-issue-tracker/issues/4112). Issues since then about the related `LEAVE` phaser include [1](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/2380), [2](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/4403), [3](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/issues/4521). So don't hold your breath for `leave`...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Raku supports similar control flow with [given](https://docs.raku.org/language/control#given) blocks.

Here's a fairly literal translation (i.e., not necessarily idiomatic Raku) from the Perl code you posted:

```raku
given * {
    for ^6 -> $item {
        succeed if $item == 6;
    }
    default { print "No items matched!\n"; }
}
```

**edit**: Oh, and for a less-literally-translated/more-idiomatic-Raku solution, well, TIMTOWTDI but I might go with `return`ing from an anonymous `sub`:

```raku
sub { for ^6 { return when 6 }
      say "No items matched!" }()
```

(Of course, I suppose it's possible that the **most** Raku-ish way to solve do that doesn't involve any Raku syntax at all – but instead involves [modifying one of Raku's braided languages](http://blogs.perl.org/users/damian_conway/2019/09/itchscratch.html) to allow `for` loops to take an `else` block.  But I'm not advising those sort of shenanigans!)

Comment: "If you are not inside a when or default block, it is an error to try to use `proceed` or `succeed`." You could add a `default` block, but that only makes it more artificial.

Comment: @hobbs thanks!  I _had_ the `default` block locally – not sure how I managed to forget it in the answer ^^^

Comment: it says you can only `succeed` *out* of a `when` or `default`. That's still not right, AFAICS.

Comment: Hmm... it works in real life, the docs just say it shouldn't :)

Comment: @hobbs I was just noticing that too.  I wonder if the docs are wrong or if Rakudo is being more permissive than it should?

Comment: Thanks guys!  Great solutions.  Accepted!

Comment: Between this any Damien Conway's code, though, I'm wondering if we don't need more phasers.  But, given the number we already have, I think it's more likely that we need to somehow make more flexible phasers that maybe take a parameter or 2.  Maybe in Raku 2 :) .

Comment: @TimothyNelson See my comment on your question. There's already a `LEAVE` phaser, and a `leave` keyword that was designed to be able to apply to a labelled block. That is the solution designed precisely for your Q's scenario.

Comment: @raiph if we're bringing not-yet-implemented features into the mix, there's also a NYI [goto statement](https://github.com/Raku/roast/blob/master/S04-statements/goto.t) that would solve **every** problem :D

Comment: @codesections :) Aiui `leave ...` et al are what .@Larry designed as the block structured programming constructs for the "more flexible phasers" that .@TimothyNelson is wondering about. My guess is it would be easier to implement `leave` per design than `goto` but, much more importantly, while Raku's design presumes `goto` will one day be implemented (on the basis it is sometimes just the ticket), it's *not* block structured programming like `last`, `leave` et al. Imo `goto`'s reputation as generally evil is valid, and use of it to just leave a block would be an anti-pattern. You agree, right?

Comment: Referencing: https://design.raku.org/S04.html#The_goto_statement

Comment: @raiph Agreed about the LEAVE phaser.  It'd be nice, though, if a) it was possible to pass a topicaliser to phasers (the same as given) that defaulted to something like maybe &?BLOCK, and b) if there were an easy way to detect if &?BLOCK had exited without an exception (not even a Control Exception).